# What does the function getName do in symfony 2 form

Tags: php, symfony

This is my form class

```
class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user')
            ->add('comment')

        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sample_staticbundle_commenttype';
    }
}
```

I am not able to get what getName function does

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is used when rendering the twig templates for that form. It lets you override the default widgets but only for that particular form by specifying a block like, for example:

```
{% block sample_staticbundle_commenttype_widget %}
```

Comment: so u mean its same as  `{% render 'SampleStaticBUndle:Comment:new' with { 'blog_id': blog.id } %}`

Comment: no, i mean the actual form field itself. For example these are the default form field twig blocks https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig but each named form can be overriden individually if you create a block using it's name

Comment: in Symfony3 You must use `getBlockPrefix()` instead of `getName()`